# Why do I not have the $MAIL environment variable?

Tags: thunderbird, email, environment-variables, gmail

I read that the `$MAIL` shell environment variable is one of the most common ones, and stores the location of my mailbox file, where my emails are stored.

I looked into the `/var/spool/mail` and `/var/mail` directories, and there are no files or directories in them at all (checked with `cd /var/spool/mail; ls` as well as checking `Show Hidden Files` under the `View` menu.

Yet I have Thunderbird Mail running and do have mail coming in from my GMail.

So my (related) question is two-fold - Where are my emails kept? And why is my `$MAIL` environment variable not defined?

Answer (score 1):

The `$MAIL` variable points to the location of your *system* mail account (i.e. where Postfix, Exim, ... would drop your mails when using the `sendmail` or `mail` to send a mail to a local user), however this variable is not used by any graphical E-Mail client I know of -- Which is probably why is its not defined.

Thunderbird stores your E-Mail in these directories:

- `~/.thunderbird/<ProfileName>/Mail` for local messages (sent messages and messages obtained via POP3)
- `~/.thunderbird/<ProfileName>/ImapMail` for downloaded IMAP messages

Note: `<ProfileName>` is the name of your user Thunderbird user profile and will look similar to this: `e7d2hvg8.default`.

Comment: So if I download and install Postfix (which I actually don't know how to at the moment, actually), I will have the $MAIL variable set automatically? A bit of topic, but I also don't have the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems like the `$MAIL` variable is set for all new user logins after the `/var/mail` directory has been created, however Postfix might also be involved somehow... Anyway installing software is done through `apt-get` or `aptitude` on command line (i.e.: `sudo aptitude install postfix`), there is also the Software Center for higher level and Synaptic for lower level package management if you prefer GUIs. OT: What's your background? REHL? SLES? BSD? Mac?

Comment: Also `$PROMPT_COMMAND` can be set in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've used Windows all my life, never touched Unix or Linux til this week. I want to learn Linux because I think managing my own server would be really cool! And most servers run Linux.